# How to aggregate multiple json field in kafka streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In below code, I want to aggregate record on "job" and "country" field both. Currently i am able to aggregate only on "job" attribute.

```
final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

KStream<String, JsonNode> personDetail = builder.stream("person-streams-input", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
KTable<String,Long> articleagg = personDetail
                .groupBy((key,value) -> value.get("job").asText(), Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
                .count();
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "zipcode": "111111",
  "job": "engineer",
  "country": "USA"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can build any `groupBy` condition based by message key and value:

```
KTable<String,Long> articleagg = personDetail
                .groupBy((key,value) -> getGroupByCondition(value), Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
                .count();


 private static String getGroupByCondition(JsonNode value) {
        return value.get("job").asText() + "_" + value.get("country").asText();
 }
```